# Inequality constraint to ensure that two shifted axis-aligned ellipsoids do not intersect

Tags: geometry

Suppose I have two identical, axis-aligned, translated ellipsoids described by
$$
E_1 = \{Dx + p : \|x\|_2 = 1\},\quad E_2 = \{Dx + q: \|x\|_2 = 1\}
$$
where $D$ is a positive diagonal matrix. I want to create an inequality constraint in an optimization problem (where $p$ and $q$ are the decision variables) to ensure that the two ellipsoids do not intersect. So I actually seek any expression that is negative when the ellipsoids intersect and nonnegative otherwise.

I feel that it should be some simple function of $D$, $p$, and $q$, but it is eluding me right now. I also think the closest points should lie on the line connecting $p$ and $q$, since we are basically dealing with spheres in a stretched coordinate system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting some sleep, the inequality constraint in its simplified form:
$$
(p-q)^T D^{-2} (p-q) \geq 4
$$

Comment: What inequality exactly are you computing here? I thught you wanted to compute $d$, the (squared?!?) minimal distance. How does that relate to what you have here, and why?

Comment: Sorry, the question was poorly worded. I should not post questions at 2 AM. I want to create an inequality constraint to enforce that the two ellipsoids do not intersect. I edited the question.